# Can I deduce marital status after observing person

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [percentage calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140891/percentage-calculation)

After reinterpret  this question
[percentage calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140891/percentage-calculation/140894#140894)
I have idea that, by observing person not only name I could not, but also marital status I can't deduce, so  answer would be  $2/8*100=25$%, sorry for repeating question, (tomorrow I have midterm so wanted to  know actual answer on this question)

Comment: Please make this question self-contained.

Comment: why?is not possible to answer or?

Comment: @dato: Please see [this meta answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/2675).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are: Name, Age, Gender, Height, Weight, Eye color, Hair color and Marital status, and you are asked which of these you cannot deduce by observation.

Can you deduce a person's weight by observation alone?
Can you deduce a person's age?

Perhaps it depends on your powers of observation. Good luck with your midterm.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yE4pj2w2KCQ

Comment: thanks very much@Daniel Pietrobon

Comment: i will try to ask it teachers,thanks guys